# Behave, multiple steps with same name

Tags: python-3.x, gherkin, python-behave

I have two feature files:

```
delete.feature
new_directory.feature
```

And two step files:

```
delete.py 
new_directory.py
```

Each one of the feature files begins like this:

```
Background:
  Given 'Workspace has the following structure'
```

Following the different tables.

When i write in step file decorator:

```
 @given('Workspace has the following structure')
```

How does it know which feature file background belongs? When I run behave for

> new_directory.feature

I can see that it runs that step from delete.feature. Is there any way to make difference between those files except from having all unique step names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I've resolved having a shared step is to use a single implementation for the step that works differently depending on the feature that is using the step. Adapted to what you describe, it would be something like:

```
@given('Workspace has the following structure') 
def step_impl(context):
    feature = context.feature

    name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(feature.filename))[0]
    if name == "delete":
        # do something
        ...
    elif name == "new_directory":
        # do something else
        ...
    else:
        raise Exception("can't determine how to run this step")
```

The code above is based on checking the base name (minus extension) of the file that contains the feature. You could also check the actual feature name but I consider file names to be more stable than feature names so I prefer to test file names.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I've been looking for! :)